# Integrate existing blog code into Django-CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

If I already have a blog app done with Django and I want to use it with my new Django CMS site, is it *okay* to simply drop it into my new Django CMS project as a decoupled app and match anything /blog/ to the blog app as apposed to a Django CMS plugin? I guess what I need to know is when is it best to write my Django app as a plugin vs an entire app?

Thx

JeffC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you don't just drop it into the `urls.py`, instead you can write an [AppHook](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#app-hooks) to tie your blog's URL scheme to a particular page in your CMS.

[Plugins](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/custom_plugins.html#writing-a-custom-plugin) on the other hand are useful if you want to inserts particular aspects of you app into other page's placeholders - for example to show your latest 3 posts on the frontpage.

You might also want to include your blog's paths in a breadcrumb or menu on your site - in that case you need to write a custom [Menu](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html#menus) too.

Finally, it might also be useful to [make use of django cms's placeholders in you blog model](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/extending_cms/placeholders.html). His would allow you to post a variety of content via plugins.

Comment: 1+ for the "placeholders" link